# what function in php can count amount of posts by users

Tags: php

Peace. I have a system I developed. with php in my framework.
What function can count the amount of posts that X users post?
I want to create a function that will show me the amount of actions a particular user has made under a variable that I will create. A variable related to posts on my site.

Does anyone have an idea how can I implement this? You do not need something genius, just count me the amount of actions a particular user did under a certain definition.

Comment: normally this is calculated  form db .. with a query ..

Comment: Do you have to give me direction how to implement it?

Comment: Your request is a bit wide ,   you are able to connect the db in php  ?  .. see how  .. and how acces  to the data..

Comment: sure, my website are connect to db.

Comment: Then  show  your tables related schema  ..